# Cisco ASA Determine If Configuration Has Been Saved

Tags: cisco-asa

On the Cisco ASA, changes to the running-config are not automatically saved to the startup-config. This is done manually with "write memory" or "copy running-config startup-config" to write the changes to flash storage.

I would like to **verify whether configuration changes have been saved rather than blindly saving repetitively** (which I currently do). I've searched Google for commands to check whether the running-config changes have been saved to startup-config, and here are two ugly workarounds that I've found:

1. "**reload**" command

   - Output of "**System config has been modified. Save? [Y]es/[N]o:**" when config needs to be saved.
   - Output of "Proceed with reload? [confirm]" when config has already been saved. ANSWER NO or similar to avoid needless reboot!!
2. **Copy** BOTH your running-config AND startup-config **to text files**.

   - Use a "**diff**" utility to compare the text files for differences.

I would love to have a quick clean command or procedure to use to verify the configuration has been saved without risking an accidental reboot. Please post if you have suggestions.

Comment: try show flash, and compare the config file date, to see if it was written

Comment: Hello @yagmoth555, I tried "show flash" but the default startup-config is a hidden file not visible from that command. I did however use a similar technique to come up with a solution - posting answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a single-command solution, but using a couple commands we can determine whether running configuration has been saved without using the "reload" command.

- `show running-config | include checksum:`
- `show startup-config | include checksum:`

If the **checksum matches, then the running-config has been saved**. You can also review the difference between last modification time of running-config and last save time of startup-config. This is less exact because the values will never be the same (startup-config should be newer than running-config after saving).

- `show version | include modified`
- `show startup-config | include Written`

I prefer the first solution comparing each checksum, but the alternate method comparing modification and written dates works well too.

Comment: Short versions: `show run | include sum:` and `show start | include sum:` - this makes it quicker to type :-). Don't forget to `write mem` if they don't match!